# JPA: select random row

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, named-query

This is my JPA ENTITY

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({  
        @NamedQuery(name = "Question.randQuestion", query = "SELECT q FROM Question AS q ORDER BY     RANDOM")
})
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question implements Serializable {
.....
}
```

The problem is:
eclipse gives me an error for this namedQuery. It says:
"The identification variable 'RANDOM' is not defined in the FROM clause"

I've tried also with RAND() instead of RANDOM and also NEWID().

Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT q FROM Question AS q ORDER BY RANDOM()` but it would return all the rows with random order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random select rows via JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459119/random-select-rows-via-jpa)

Answer (score 6):

To get a Random Row, first get list of total question and get any one.

```
public Question  getRandomQuestion(EntityManager em) {
  Query countQuery = em.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from Question");
  long count = (Long)countQuery.getSingleResult();

  Random random = new Random();
  int number = random.nextInt((int)count);

  Query selectQuery = em.createQuery("select q from Question q");
  selectQuery.setFirstResult(number);
  selectQuery.setMaxResults(1);
  return (Question)selectQuery.getSingleResult();
}
```

Note: You may need to implement a logic to avoid duplicates while calling method more than once.

Comment: if I understand right, you gave solution for randomizing 1 question. but if I want some few ? I tried to do setMaxResult(4) for getting 4 questions from DB, but it gives me 4 questions at the same order it is in the DB (let's say the first one being randomized is question number 5, the other 3 questions from DB would be number 6,7 and 8) but I want the other 3 questions to be randomized too. what is the best way to do this ?Thanks

Comment: @user3168286 you need to call this method n time to get n random questions. Also you may need to implement a logic to skip duplicate since random number is used

Comment: @Mr.Pichler did you try that before down vote ? I answered assuming ids starts from (1,2,3....n).

Comment: @Mr.Pichler where is the persist happen here in select query.

Comment: @vels4j I removed my comments. Sorry for the down voting. If you edit your question I can remove it. What happened is that I down voted your answer instead the previous answer that I wanted it. Also my comments was target to the other answer.

Comment: @Mr.Pichler ok no problem

Comment: @vels4j Removed the down vote, and about your answer, it's work perfectly.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Answer (score 2):

I had to solve a specific case of this problem where I had to select random records from a set of records matching a certain input criteria. The solution also had to support limit. I describe my solution below starting with assumptions.

**Assumptions:**

> - Given the set of criteria as input, it is possible to count number of records that match a selection criteria, as supported by the `org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>.count(Predicate predicate)` method.
> - Pages are zero indexed.
> - It is possible to request specific page as supported by the `org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest(int page, int size)` method.

**Algorithm**

> 1. Count all records matching the input criteria.
> 2. Calculate total number of pages based on the count and specified limit.
> 3. Generate a random page index in range [0, total pages).
> 4. Request the page with index generated in previous step.
> 5. Shuffle elements in the returned page.

**Code**

```
Long totalRecords = someRepository.count(somePredicate);
Long totalPages =
    (totalRecords % someLimit == 0)
        ? (totalRecords / someLimit)
        : ((totalRecords / someLimit) + 1);
int pageIndex = (int) (Math.random() * totalPages);

PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(pageIndex, someLimit);
Page<T> somePage = someRepository.findAll(somePredicate, pageRequest);
List<T> someList;
if (somePage.getTotalElements() > 0) {
  someList = new ArrayList<>(somePage.getContent());
} else {
  someList = new ArrayList<>();
}

Collections.shuffle(someList);
```

The second shuffle is to ensure records within the page are also randomized. The general case of this solution is that there is no criteria and so the `count()` has to be invoked with no `predicate` thus getting a count of all rows in the table.

Comment: The constructor `PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(pageIndex, someLimit)` is deprecated, so we can use `PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(pageIndex, someLimit)` instead.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand you want to select random question from the table. You'd rather use WHERE clause, with providing some parameter from your code, like:

```
SELECT q FROM Question AS q WHERE id = :id
```

Then in the code, which creates your query you must generate random id to be selected:

```
query.setParam("id", getRandomId());
```

And to get random id, you may want to query number of rows from DB and use `java.util.Random.nextInt(rowsCount)` (if all ids are there, of course).

Btw, something similar is described here: http://www.shredzone.de/cilla/page/53/how-to-fetch-a-random-entry-with-hibernate.html

Comment: This only works if ids are contiguous on the database.

Comment: apart from what @JamesNewman mentioned, [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) can return `0`

Comment: .. and the maximum is exclusive, so you should add 1 to the random result.