# MySQL random records via JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I need a JPA query which returns 10 random records from database. I use mysql database.

This example doesn't work:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM People p ORDER BY rand()");
q.setMaxResults(10).getResultList();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459119/random-select-rows-via-jpa

Comment: what "doesn't work"? rand is not a valid JPQL function as any doc would tell you (and that other thread does). So use JPA 2.1 "function" to call a native SQL function .... called RAND