# How to get limited random results using Spring Boot Repositories

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a database with many fornames and names packed in "Person" Entity. Also I use Spring Boot with @Repository to access the data.

I want to achieve something like that.

> give random 5 results.

Is there an easy way to achieve it with Repository Annotations? Without writing native query?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459119/random-select-rows-via-jpa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random select rows via JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459119/random-select-rows-via-jpa)